# Cron job with passing arguments runtime

Tags: python, unix, cron

How can I run the cron job With arguments given rutime?

The scenario is I am running a python script as cron . Runtime if I pass few arguments it should accept and do some work and if I don't pass arguments it should continue its scheduled work..

Note : Arguments are passed runtime not at scheduling the cron job.

Can any one help on this quickly??.

Well I know this is weird situation?? But this is the requirement...

If not with cron is there any way to schedule and get the job done??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Passed from whence? From the crontab? From the user's console? ?

Comment: From console I have to pass  arguments

Comment: Can you describe the use case more clearly? So you want your job to run periodically, say, every day at 4:00AM, with the default parameters. Additionally you want the user to be able to run the job on demand, with user-specified parameters. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly Rob . I have solved it implementing some other logic.Thanks All for help

Answer (score 0):

Since you saying that your arguments will dynamically change, I would advise you to take a look at [APScheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Documentation is pretty good, and you can "copy and paste" examples to get a sense of what is it.

In a few words - you can run it on the background and trigger the jobs at any time.